# validate XML in all opened documents in Notepad++

Tags: xml, xsd, notepad++, xml-validation

I am using the xml-tools plugin in notepad++ to run validation on .xml files using an .xsd schema file.

But I have hundreds of files to validate, and will likely have hundreds more.

I really like how Notepad++ handles "find all in all documents" and was wondering if there was a way to do a run-plugin-function-in-all-opened-documents within notepad.

Alternately, if there is another, better way of mass validating .xml that would solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are command line tools, which could be used via a batch/shell script depending on your environment. [This](http://xmlvs.sourceforge.net/) is implemented in perl and should do, [here](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~ht/xsv-status.html) is a link to a Win32 installer.